# Black status bar turns white when quitting iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I gave my iPhone app a black status bar by adding the UIStatusBarStyleOpaqueBlack / UIStatusBarStyle to the Info.plist file. It works great most of the time. The black status bar shows when the app is running and when the Default.png is being shown.

The issue is when I quit the app by pressing the home button, the status bar becomes a white block while the iPhone's standard quit animation is taking place. I haven't seen this issue with any other apps that use a black status bar.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This sound like a bug to me. Even if your application was misbehaving, the iPhone OS should not be affected when your application is not running anymore.

Comment: FWIW, I have seen this behavior with a couple of iPhone apps, so it's not just you.

Comment: This has been bugging me for ages -- thanks for asking!

Comment: This issue only appear in Simulator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the background color of your window to black.

```
[self.view.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: Kind of obvious in hindsight! Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I just had the same problem on an iPad, but in inverse. I had a white nav bar & status bar, but when quitting the app pressing the home button (and relaunching the app pressing the app's icon), the status bar and nav bar would go black. So, I set the window to white instead, and this works. In my case, the problem has something to do with the storyboard. Looking over my backups, I can restore a previous storyboard and the problem goes away. (Of course, I made changes to the storyboard since then that I don't want to loose). I looked through the storyboard xml but nothing was obviously wrong.