# iOS7 canDisplayBannerAds UITbarBar Issue

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I am currently updating one of my applications and after following the WWDC session video I am trying to use canDisplayBannerAds = YES on my view controller which resides in a UITabBarController which is set up as a translucent TabBar.

However when the ads appear it is adding a black tab bar behind the existing one and furthermore when you switch apps you can see that the tab bar is black.

Is there a way to change this or does this only work with ViewControllers which are not part of a UITabBarController?

[image: The TabBar appears darker when the Ad is loaded]

[image: Switching between apps the TabBar shows as being black]

Thanks Aaron

Comment: I'm running into something like this too. In my case, I have ads on the bottom of the view, and the black temporarily appears behind the nag bar at the top of the screen when switching to the app or switching away from the app. No solution yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris I've also still not found a solution for it so in the end added the iAd in the app the traditional way however I had to turn off transparent status bars to get it working as it was still hiding below :(

Comment: Yep. I've had to turn off translucent tab bars in my case. I'll be looking more into this shortly, and will get back to you.

Comment: I resolved my problem, but I'm not sure that your problem is the same. After spending most of the day hacking on my code, looking at backups that didn't have the problem, I found a solution on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876530/black-status-bar-turns-white-when-quitting-iphone-app